# Implement Coding Guidelines using Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper, configure

In my project there are some coding standered we need to follow for Web Api. 
Is there any way we can configure these instruction in Resharper? I am using Resharper Ultimate edition. Also can we configure resharper such a way that, if these instruction are not followed then it will throw an error and show suggestions.

The guidelines contains common instruction like:

```
Use Camel case in Payload
    Use camel case for the data elements in the payload.    Eg:firstName,lastName                                                                                                                                                 
Use lowercase in Endpoints
    Use only lower case when defining the endpoints.                
    Eg:  GET \api\v1\customers\{CustomerID}\rewards                                                                

Use hyphen for compound words in Endpoints
    Use hyphen for compound words in Endpoints.                 
    Eg: GET \api\v1\customers\{CustomerId}\order-history    

Use Nouns not verbs 
    Noun based endpoint should be used rather than verb based endpoint for CRUD operations.                                              
    Eg:     GET \api\v1\\customers, GET \api\v1\customers\{CustomerID}                                                        
            GET \api\v1\GetAllCustomers

Use verb followed by noun in case of certain functions.                                    
    Eg: PUT \api\v1\customers\{CustomerID}\send-email
```

Comment: Thanks all for quick reply. But I need more customization.  
e.g. if some one defines endpoints as captial case letter [Route("Seller/Search/{Page}/{PageSize}")] then it should throw error and suggest to iplement as [Route("seller/search/{page}/{pageSize}")]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for StyleCop, along with its Resharper plugin. StyleCop "analyzes C# source code to enforce a set of style and consistency rules", including rules which you can write yourself.

https://github.com/StyleCop

Comment: Thanks for help. This can be achieved by writing custom rule by using StyleCop https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/wiki/Authoring-a-Custom-StyleCop-Rule

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Options menu from Resharper in Visual-Studio you can configure such things. If you scroll to the bottom of your Optionslist you can find different Nodes for every language which is supported. There you can configure Uppercase, Lowercase or the Brace Layout for example. The Screenshot shows you some conventions for C#.[image]

I don't know a way which enables error notifications for that. But there is a Shortcut which uses your configured Styles for a whole file (Strg+E+F in my case). So if someone didn't use your conventions and you open a class of him, you just press the combination and the document is styled. Maybe this can also be integrated to Build-Processes via Jenkins or sth. But I haven't tried this out yet.

If you goto Resharper->Manage Options you can export your new settings to file. Your collegues can import this settings the same way you export it.